# How does YOLO handle non-class objects?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I have been reading more about computer vision and I'm bothered by YOLO and similar deep learning architectures.

The thing I am confused about is how non-class image sections are dealt with. In particular, it's not clear to me at all why YOLO doesn't consider every part of an image a possible class.

What actually sets the cutoff for detection and then classification?

Answer (score 2):

The output of YOLO is (x,y,w,h,confidence,class). The confidence value presents whether the rectangle holds an object, the rectangle is non-classed when confidence is low.

The `class` value will be used, only when `confidence` is high.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it is not possible to detect the non-class object. You have to train that non-class object again then the model will detect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).